# jquery object items in array not defined

Tags: jquery

I have an array filled with objects like so:

```
var taskArray = [{
    id: 247,
    value: "Pin Lot"
}, {
    id: 249,
    value: "Excavate"
}, {
    id: 245,
    value: "Water & Sewer Installed"
}, {
    id: 246,
    value: "Pin Footings"
}, {
    id: 248,
    value: "Footings"
}, {
    id: 251,
    value: "Footing Inspection & Pour"
}, {
    id: 250,
    value: "Foundation Walls"
}];
```

and when I go console logs like so:

```
console.log(taskArray);
console.log(taskArray[0].taskId, taskArray[0].task);
```

it says the array is empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The objects have properties named `id` and `value`. Where is `taskId` and `task` coming from? That's the problem

Comment: Like the above try mentioned `taskArray[0].id` and `taskArray[0].value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects in your array do not have properties `taskId` and `task`. Do this instead

```
console.log(taskArray[0].id, taskArray[0].value);
```

Either use above or create your array with objects having properties `taskId` and `task`.

```js
var taskArray = [{
    id: 247,
    value: "Pin Lot"
}, {
    id: 249,
    value: "Excavate"
}, {
    id: 245,
    value: "Water & Sewer Installed"
}, {
    id: 246,
    value: "Pin Footings"
}, {
    id: 248,
    value: "Footings"
}, {
    id: 251,
    value: "Footing Inspection & Pour"
}, {
    id: 250,
    value: "Foundation Walls"
}, {
    id: 252,
    value: "Basement Backfill"
}, {
    id: 253,
    value: "Steel Beams"
}, {
    id: 254,
    value: "Framing and Exterior"
}, {
    id: 254,
    value: "Framing"
}, {
    id: 300,
    value: "Brick Received"
}, {
    id: 255,
    value: "Roof Ply"
}, {
    id: 258,
    value: "Windows Install"
}, {
    id: 259,
    value: "Heating R/I"
}, {
    id: 261,
    value: "Plumbing R/I"
}, {
    id: 256,
    value: "Shingle Roof (Upper)"
}, {
    id: 276,
    value: "Pour Basement Floors"
}, {
    id: 257,
    value: "Stairs Install"
}, {
    id: 310,
    value: "Back-Framing"
}, {
    id: 260,
    value: "Electrical R/I"
}, {
    id: 265,
    value: "Kitchen Measure"
}, {
    id: 262,
    value: "Alarm/Vac/Cable/Phone R/I"
}, {
    id: 311,
    value: "Frame Check"
}, {
    id: 322,
    value: "Frame Pass"
}, {
    id: 289,
    value: "Exterior Brick Work"
}, {
    id: 290,
    value: "Exterior Siding"
}, {
    id: 317,
    value: "Shingle Roof (Lower)"
}, {
    id: 209,
    value: "Drywall"
}, {
    id: 307,
    value: "Furnace & Ductwork"
}, {
    id: 266,
    value: "Insulation"
}, {
    id: 277,
    value: "Insulation Inspection"
}, {
    id: 263,
    value: "Hydro Meter"
}, {
    id: 309,
    value: "Gas Meter"
}, {
    id: 267,
    value: "Drywall Walls/Ceilings"
}, {
    id: 268,
    value: "Taping"
}, {
    id: 270,
    value: "Prime"
}, {
    id: 273,
    value: "Install Railings and Nosing"
}, {
    id: 274,
    value: "Install Ceramics"
}, {
    id: 278,
    value: "Install Trim"
}, {
    id: 308,
    value: "Drywall Check"
}, {
    id: 324,
    value: "1st Finish Tech Inspection"
}, {
    id: 323,
    value: "Paint Interior"
}, {
    id: 280,
    value: "Paint Exterior"
}, {
    id: 279,
    value: "Install Kitchen"
}, {
    id: 326,
    value: "Back-Trim"
}, {
    id: 281,
    value: "Complete Electrical"
}, {
    id: 282,
    value: "Complete Heating"
}, {
    id: 284,
    value: "Complete Cable/Phone"
}, {
    id: 283,
    value: "Complete Plumbing"
}, {
    id: 327,
    value: "Occupancy Inspection"
}, {
    id: 288,
    value: "Install Carpet"
}, {
    id: 325,
    value: "2nd Finish Tech Inspection"
}, {
    id: 328,
    value: "Paint Touch-up"
}, {
    id: 330,
    value: "QA Inspection"
}, {
    id: 329,
    value: "1st Clean"
}, {
    id: 298,
    value: "PDI"
}, {
    id: 316,
    value: "PDI Deficiencies"
}, {
    id: 331,
    value: "2nd Clean"
}];

console.log(taskArray[0].id, taskArray[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accesing wrong properties .It should be

```
console.log(taskArray[0].id, taskArray[0].value);
```